# JavaScript array.push() for object

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I try to Insert new data in an object as an object.
But the problem is when i use array.push() method it inserts new data/data's in a array first then push it into my desire object but as an array.

here is the code

`var new_data = this.filter_posts.slice(0,3);
this.current_posts.push(new_data);`

and for understand purpose i post ta console log
[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDBgh.png)

Comment: Object does not have a push method.... Show more code than what you provided. My guess is you do not want it pushed as an array, but as individual items.

Comment: `this.current_posts` is an object or an array?

Comment: from the dupe: `[].push.apply(this.current_posts, new_data)`

Comment: here is the full code https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d88W7scnGbmTRiDQpKnWqQvuiDnAbyoF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @prerak-sola your solution looks good, I think its working, thank's man, god bless you. `` this.current_posts.push.apply(this.current_posts, new_data)``

Answer (score 0):

Try using spread operator `this.current_posts.push(...new_data);`

```js
var x = []
var y = []

var items = [1,2,3]

// what you are doing:
x.push(items)

console.log(x)

// what you need
y.push(...items)

console.log(y)
```